# How to iterate over nested data classes using kotlin and refelction

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have a data class called **report** which is essentially a list of lists of variables - so nested data classes.

```
data class report(
    var list1 : List1,
    var list2 : List2
) : Parcelable

data class List1 (
    var a: Boolean = false,
    var b: Boolean = false,
) : Parcelable 


data class List2 (
    var c : Boolean = false,
    var d : Boolean = false,
) : Parcelable
```

Using Kotlin and reflection I have a for loop which iterates over the top level data class and prints the name of the variable successfully. I'd like to iterate over each nested class and print the variables names but I can't figure out how to do that without explicitly referencing the nested class by name. The first for loop prints the correct data but the second for loop just prints "length".

```
        for (prop in report::class.memberProperties) {
            Log.d("DATACLASS", "${prop.name}")
            for (subProp in prop::class.memberProperties){
                Log.d("DATACLASS", "${subProp.name}")
            }
        }
```

In the second loop I feel like "prop" is not being expanded properly as a reference to the nested class. I tried something like "report.prop.name" or "report.${prop.name})" without success. I also tried assigning report.prop.name to a separate variable. Is this a simple syntax issue I'm missing? I did read other similar questions on Stack but didn't find a solution.   Is it something to do perhaps with not having a class instance created at the right moment?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to iterate over properties of potentially different types - so reflection has no way to know what the type is after the top level.

`report::class.declaredMemberProperties` returns a collection containing `KMutableProperty1` objects. You can't derive the generic type of the `KMutableProperty1` because generics are erased, so could be potentially anything. Of course **you** know that they are `KMutableProperty1<record, List1>` and `KMutableProperty1<record, List2>`, but you are looking at it at compile-time, with generics. Reflection has to do it dynamically at runtime with no generics, and so when using reflection you only know the type as `KMutableProperty1`.

I believe this means is that there is no way to dynamically loop over the properties as you describe, because the property types are not known at runtime. The only way to do it would be to declare the type of each property explicitly, but that sort of defeats the point:

```
fun <T : Any> KClass<T>.printPropertyNames(): Unit {
    for (prop in declaredMemberProperties) {
        println("$this: ${prop.name}")
    }
}

fun main() {
    Report::class.printPropertyNames()
    for (prop in Report::class.declaredMemberProperties) {
        when (prop.name) {
            "list1" -> List1::class.printPropertyNames()
            "list2" -> List2::class.printPropertyNames()
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
class Report: list1
class Report: list2
class List1: a
class List1: b
class List2: c
class List2: d
```

If you just want to see what's in the object however, you can use data class's default `toString()` behaviour:

```
println(Report(List1(true, false), List2(false, true)))
```

Output:

```
Report(list1=List1(a=true, b=false), list2=List2(c=false, d=true))
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. Does this explain why I can't reference the nested classes using my abstract function? Something like: `println (report.prop.name)`

Comment: The problem is that `prop` is a `KMutableProperty1`, so `subProp` represents the properties of the `KMultableProperty1` class, not `List1`, `List2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do this with a function and a for loop like so:

```
fun <T> printProperty(instance: T, prop: KProperty1<T, *>): Any? {
        println("${prop.name} = ${prop.get(instance)}")
        return prop.get(instance)
    }

for (rep in MyReport::class.memberProperties) {
        val reportProperty = MyReport::class.memberProperties.single{ it.name == rep.name}
        val reportInstance = printProperty(report, reportProperty)
        for (subRep in reportInstance!!::class.memberProperties) {
            println("${subRep.name} = ${subRep.getter.call(reportInstance)}")
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure why but I couldn't use my function a second time in the second for loop - instead I had to use getter.call in order to get the value I wanted.